# Detector de dedos (ERROR) CV2

Tags: python, cv2

estoy haciendo un programa y resulta que me da un **error** este es el código:

```
import math
import cv2
from cv2 import FILLED
import mediapipe as mp
import time

class detectormanos():
    #Parametros de detección
    def __init__(self, mode = False, maxManos = 2, Confdeteccion = 0.5, Confsegui = 0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxManos = maxManos
        self.Confdeteccion = Confdeteccion
        self.Confsegui = Confsegui


        self.mpmanos = mp.solutions.hands
        self.manos = self.mpmanos.Hands(self.mode, self.maxManos, self.Confdeteccion, self.Confsegui)
        self.dibujo = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
        self.tip = [4,8,12,16,20]

    def encontrarmanos(self, frame, dibujar = True):
        imgcolor = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.resultados = self.manos.process(imgcolor)

        if self.resultados.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for mano in self.resultados.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if dibujar:
                    self.dibujo.draw_landmarks(frame, mano, self.mpmanos.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
            
        return frame


    def encontrarposicion(self, frame, ManoNum = 0, dibujar = True):
        xlista = []
        ylista = []
        bbox = []
        self.lista = []
        if self.resultados.multi_hand_landmarks:
            miMano = self.resultados.multi_hand_landmarks[ManoNum]
            for id, lm in enumerate(miMano.landmark):
                alto, ancho, c = frame.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * ancho), int(lm.y * alto)
                xlista.append(cx)
                ylista.append(cy)
                self.lista.append([id,cx,cy])
                if dibujar:
                    cv2.circle(frame,(cx,cy),5,(0,0,0), cv2.FILLED)
            
            xmin, xmax = min(xlista), max(xlista)
            ymin, ymax = min(ylista), max(ylista)
            bbox = xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax
            if dibujar:
                cv2.rectangle(frame,(xmin-20,ymin-20),(xmax+20,ymax+20),(0,255,0),2)

        return self.lista, bbox

    def dedosarriba(self):
        dedos = []
        if self.lista[self.tip[0]][1] > self.lista[self.tip[0]-1][1]:
            dedos.append(1)

        else:
            dedos.append(0)

        for id in range(1,5):
            if self.lista[self.tip[id]][2] < self.lista[self.tip[id]-2][2]:
                dedos.append(1)

            else:
                dedos.append(0)

        return dedos

    def distancia(self, p1, p2, frame, dibujar = True, r=15, t=3):
        x1,y1=self.lista[p1][1:]
        x2,y2=self.lista[p2][1:]
        cx, cy = (x1+x2) // 2, (y1+y2)//2
        if dibujar:
            cv2.line(frame,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),t)
            cv2.circle(frame,(x1,y1),r,(0,0,255),cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.circle(frame,(x2,y2),r,(0,0,255),cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.circle(frame,(cx,cy),r,(0,0,255),cv2.FILLED)

        length=math.hypot(x2-x1,y2-y1)

        return length, frame, [x1,y1,x2,y2,cx,cy]


def main():
    ptiempo = 0
    ctiempo = 0
    
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    detector = detectormanos()

    while True:
        ret,frame = cap.read()
        frame = detector.encontrarmanos(frame)
        lista, bbox = detector.encontrarposicion(frame)

        ctiempo = time.time()
        fps = 1/(ctiempo - ptiempo)
        ptiempo = ctiempo

        cv2.putText(frame,str(int(fps)),(10,70),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,3,(255,0,255),3)

        cv2.imshow("Camera",frame)
        k = cv2.waitKey(1)

        if k == 27:
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


main()
```

Este es el error al parecer esta línea `self.manos = self.mpmanos.Hands(self.mode, self.maxManos, self.Confdeteccion, self.Confsegui)`y no entiendo cual es el problema si todo esta bien escrito

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "d:\pingüi_pruebas\camcv2\camera.py", line 118, in <module>
    main()   File "d:\pingüi_pruebas\camcv2\camera.py", line 95, in main     
    detector = detectormanos()   File "d:\pingüi_pruebas\camcv2\camera.py", line 17, in __init__ 
    self.manos = self.mpmanos.Hands(self.mode, self.maxManos, self.Confdeteccion, sel f.Confsegui)   File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mediapi pe\python\solutions\hands.py", line 114, in __init__
    super().__init__(   File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mediapi pe\python\solution_base.py", line 258, in __init__
    self._input_side_packets = {   File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 259, in <dictcomp>
    name: self._make_packet(self._side_input_type_info[name], data)   File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 513, in _make_packet
    return getattr(packet_creator, 'create_' + packet_data_type.value)(data) TypeError: create_int(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: int) -> mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.packet.Packet

Invoked with: 0.5 [ WARN:0] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ
Lo he estado intentando muchas veces cambiar las cosas y la verdad me he quedado sin opciones, y quiero que me devuelva el numero de dedos, este proyecto serviría para cuanto hayan una cantidad de dedos realice una acciónㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas pasando a `Hands()` parámetros de forma posicional y según se menciona en este ["issue"](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/2818#issuecomment-979842902) particularmente [aquí](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/2818), se ha agregado un parámetro nuevo: [`MODEL_COMPLEXITY`](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/hands.html#model_complexity), lo cual hace que este pasando `self.Confdeteccion` un `float` a un parámetro que espera Un entero. Te sugiero rehacer `__init__()`:

```
def __init__(self, mode = False, modelComplexity = 1, maxManos = 2, Confdeteccion = 0.5, Confsegui = 0.5):
    self.mode = mode
    self.maxManos = maxManos
    self.Confdeteccion = Confdeteccion
    self.Confsegui = Confsegui
    self.modelComplex = modelComplexity

    self.mpmanos = mp.solutions.hands
    self.manos = self.mpmanos.Hands(static_image_mode=self.mode,
                                    max_num_hands=self.maxManos,
                                    min_detection_confidence=self.Confdeteccion,
                                    model_complexity = self.modelComplex,
                                    min_tracking_confidence = self.Confsegui)

    self.dibujo = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
    self.tip = [4,8,12,16,20]
```

Pasando lo parámetros de forma nominal, evitarás problemas futuros por cambios en la API.

Ver [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1WuBOiR2ml-lD6EPHw-SuRBW0_jp6nhCG?usp=sharing)

Comment: No funciona da mismo error

Comment: Raro, te aclaro que verifiqué tu código y con el cambio, el error que mencionas desaparece.

Comment: Me podrías mandar el codigo el completo para intentarlo?

Comment: Te agregué el código competo de la función `__init__()` y te adjunte un colab con una prueba de concepto.

Comment: Gracias!, ya que mencionas Colab, me podrías ayudar con esta  [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/532593/pytorch-error-en-colab]